# Jmeter is showing wrong result from SQL Server

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a query to check the SQL Server Transaction log free space which returns different result from SQL Server and Jmeter

```
SELECT cast(round((total_log_size_in_bytes - used_log_space_in_bytes)*1.0/1024/1024,2,0) as decimal (18,2)) AS [free log SPACE IN MB]  
FROM sys.dm_db_log_space_usage;
```

In Sql Server
[image]

In Jmeter
[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Are queries executed on the same database server?

Comment: Yes. Both are executing in the same server

Comment: Probably defferent version of JDBC drivers in JMeter\lib and your DB Client Tool?